# Jackson json formatting of zoneddatetime

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need to define the JsonFormat of a ZonedDateTime in which the time is defined in a xml message.

I added the Jackson jar to format ZonedDateTime (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule)

Added the JavaTimeModule like this:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

The problem is that it cannot format the datetime correctly.
The error is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from String "2019
>   3 4 14 44 20 -5": Text '2019 3 4 14 44 20 -5' could not be parsed at
>   index 18

This is how I am defining the time pattern:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy M e k m s X")
private ZonedDateTime openDtGmt;
```

How can I map the zone pattern when it has a negative in the string?

**UPDATE**
I realize that the date is not consistent with conventions.  But this is coming from a legacy system and cannot be changed.
We need to identify the date/time pattern to be this:
4 digit year; all remaining digits do NOT have leading zeros; then a timezone without leading zeros and a sign before the digit.
Also, the timezone is GMT time.  The format for the timezone is UTC.

We replaced XmlMapper with ObjectMapper.
That seems to get us past the date/time format error but within the XML there is an empty tag in which it is failing.
If we can get past the empty tag error, we can parse the date/time with our own method.

**UPDATE**
After more testing, it seems that the error we are getting when using the ObjectMapper has to do with an empty tag. It seems that the xml string is too long. It errors at the 1000 character length.

Comment: that doesn't look like valid date pattern? should it be: 'yyyy M d k m s X' ... you can test your format at : http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/#

Comment: also keep in mind that using X timezone (ISO 8601) expect value in one of the following formats: -08; -0800; -08:00.

Comment: This date/time pattern is coming from a legacy system.  I realize it is not consistent with a normal pattern.  But I was wondering if we can create a date/time pattern that can format this input.

Comment: Maybe a better way to go would be to import this unconventional date/time as a string then create a custom parse method to change to date/time

Comment: I agree you should transform your legacy date format string into valid one before applying date formatter.

Comment: Can XmlMapper to that?  Or do I have to serialize the field into a string object and then format it?

Comment: I'd serialize to string first, alternatively take a look at building custom DateTimeFormatter.. sorry I have no examples for this

Comment: I am in the process of trying to do this.  Should I post it on this question of open another...because I would like some help