# HTTP REST Call to a spring boot application will not does not have datetime parameter in request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application deployed to the Pivotal Cloud Foundry written in java. There is a server application that makes a POST REST call to this application. In the payload is a datetime, I store the parameter as a string within a **closeRequest** object from the server application:

```
class closeRequest
{
    String dueDateGmt;
    Integer orgId;
    Boolean closeFlag;
    String strategyName;
}
```

I format the dueDateGmt like this: **2019-03-12T15:00:47-05:00**
The dueDateGmt is set in the server application.  I have debug statements to see the value.
When I use Postman to run a JSON string to the Spring Boot application, the response is successful.
When I run the application using the server application to make the REST call to the Spring Boot application, the dueDateGmt value in the Spring boot application is null.

```
class closeRequest
    {
        ZonedDateTime dueDateGmt;
        Integer orgId;
        Boolean closeFlag;
        String strategyName;
    }
```

I don't understand how to take the JSON and translate the string date to a ZonedDateTime. 
When the variable is an Integer, Float or String the mapping from 
JSON (string) -> Integer, Float, String is automatic.
Currently, this is what I am doing..

> 1. Server Application - ZonedDateTime - dueDate - converted to string
> 2. Sent to SpringBoot Application via JSON
> 3. Spring Boot Application - Displayed ZonedDateTime dueDate - it is null.

**UPDATE**

The server application gets the date from an application in an unconventional format.  It looks like this:
2019 3 5 11 30 30 -5
YYYY M D HH MM ss GMT

I transform it using a custom method that I wrote into a conventional format like this:  2019-03-12T15:00:47-05:00

This is the method:

```
 public static String formatScannerDateTimeToDateTimeString(String dateTimeString)
  {
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy d M H m s Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
      ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(adjustTZ(dateTimeString), formatter);
      return zonedDateTime.toString();
  }

  public static String adjustTZ(String dateTimeStamp)
  {
         StringBuilder adjustedDateTimeStamp = new StringBuilder(dateTimeStamp);
         if (dateTimeStamp != null)
         {
                int tzPos = dateTimeStamp.indexOf('-');
                if (tzPos > -1)
                {
                      adjustedDateTimeStamp = new StringBuilder(dateTimeStamp.substring(0, tzPos+1));
                      String tzPortion = dateTimeStamp.substring(tzPos+1);
                      adjustedDateTimeStamp.append(("00" + tzPortion).substring(tzPortion.length()));
                      adjustedDateTimeStamp.append("00");
                }
         }
         return adjustedDateTimeStamp.toString();
  }
```

Comment: How are you serializing/deserializing the ZonedDateTime? Out of the box it to-string's a time zone like "[America/Denver]".

Comment: I describe what I do to the date above under **UPDATE**.  I get the date in an unconventional format and created a custom method to translate it into a more conventional format.

Comment: OK it's kind of confusing for me everything above written - which value are you sending to your SpringBoot application? And is that the value that you have tested against that SpringBoot application?

Comment: can you also fix that styling in your question related to "...Server Application Http REST Spring Boot REST Application DateTime var -> String JSON ------------> JSON to ZonedDateTime?"

Comment: And remembering you previous question about jakson json formating - are you still using that one on SpringBoot side?! If yes you need to set correct pattern there! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046157/jackson-json-formatting-of-zoneddatetime

Comment: I am not using Jackson to map the object to json. I am sending a string to the SpringBoot application. Yes.  I tested the same dateTime string in Postman.

Comment: Updated my question and tried to clarify. Basically, once the ZonedDateTime is in the SpringBoot application it is null. I believe it is past to the application because I convert it to a string. Once I am in the REST application, the value it null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing an annotation @JsonProperties that we originally wanted to use Jackson to map the variables in the class. The only one NOT removed was the duedtgmt.  Once removed the request could be mapped on the REST side of the application